# passing .m3u8 file to AudioStreamer iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, m3u8, audiostreamer

Can any one suggest me a m3u8 parser that works on iOS 10. I used [this](https://github.com/alexsun/M3U8Paser) but its giving me errors

> M3U8_BASE_URL undecleared indentifier, No visible interface declared
>   in NSString for isExtendedM3Ufile these kind of errors,, more than 17

in `NSString+m3u8.m`. I want to pass an m3u8 file to [AudioStreamer](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer).

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Error? What error?

Comment: M3U8_BASE_URL undecleared indentifier, No visible interface declared in NSString for isExtendedM3Ufile these kind of errors,, more than 17

Comment: Did you do the import of the files?

Comment: I copied all files inside M3U8Kit folder

Comment: same errors are giving when runs the Demo project too

Answer (score 0):

[image] 
According to the screenshot, I copied all the files into one folder and import to the project.

Then m3u8 file URL to the M3U8PlaylistModel

```
       let playlistModel = M3U8PlaylistModel(url: self.m3u8_url)
        guard let m3u8PlaylistModel =  playlistModel else {
            return
        }
        guard let masterPlaylist = m3u8PlaylistModel.masterPlaylist else {
            return
        }
        guard let streamList = masterPlaylist.xStreamList else {
            return
        }

        streamList.sortByBandwidth(inOrder: .orderedAscending)

        for i in 0 ..< streamList.count {
            if let extXStreamInf = streamList.xStreamInf(at: i){

                /* you can get below properties, using this extXStreamInf object

                @property (nonatomic, readonly, assign) NSInteger bandwidth;
                @property (nonatomic, readonly, assign) NSInteger programId;        // removed by draft 12
                @property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *codecs;
                @property (nonatomic, readonly) MediaResoulution resolution;
                @property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *audio;
                @property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *video;
                @property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *subtitles;
                @property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *closedCaptions;
                @property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSURL   *URI;
            */

            }
        }
```