# How to get an array of all available sub-stream before we download an HLS stream?

Tags: ios10, http-live-streaming, m3u8, avasset, avurlasset

How to extract metadata from available HLS stream, so that i can have all available resolutions ,bandwidth and sub-stream information before i download a HLS stream. I want to allow user to choose a resolution they want to download from all available HLS Sub-stream resolution. How can i get all available sub-stream information before hand?

Comment: All that information is in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022641/passing-m3u8-file-to-audiostreamer-ios/48193180#48193180), please check that answer. What you need to do is, before stream HSL, create an M3U8PlaylistModel object. So you can get all the available sub-stream.